# React native component as typed model prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to make a class that looks like this

```
export default class IconModel {
    name: string
    title: string
    iconType: "AntDesign" | "Ionicons"
    component: React.Component //What type should be used?
    iconName: string
    size: number
}
```

What I want is to make the `component` prop only be able to be passed a react component (ex: Home.tsx)

I am then using it like this

```
import { HomeScreen } from '../../../screens';
var iconData: IconModel[] = [
    {
        component: HomeScreen,
        iconName: "appstore1",
        iconType: "AntDesign",
        ...

    <NavigationContainer>
        <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}>
            {iconData.map((x, key) => (
                    <BottomTab.Screen
                        name={x.name}
                        component={x.component}
                        options={{
                            title: x.title,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} data={x} />,
                        }}
                    />
            ))}
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Are you able to type a variable or prop as a JSX/React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to use Screen as the type for the prop

```
export default class IconModel {
    name: string
    title: string
    iconType: "AntDesign" | "Ionicons"
    component: Screen 
    iconName: string
    size: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are talking about passing a react component as a prop, you can do it using `PropTypes.elementType`

You can get more details here,

> https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes